# how to get Diffie–Hellman key exchange parameters?

Tags: ssl, encryption, diffie-hellman

I want to decrypt https stream in my https server. I have succeeded in decrypting it which used RSA secret exchange when i have private key. But I dont know how to descryt it when it uses DHE for secret exchange   because I dont have any parameters.how to get Diffie–Hellman key exchange parameters?

Answer (score 3):

This should not be possible. The whole idea behind forward secrecy is that you use Diffie-Hellman key exchange because this way a captured session cannot be decrypted later, even if an attacker gets access to the private key of the certificate.

Answer (score 3):

The "E" in DHE is for *ephemeral.* It means transient, fleeting, or temporary. The key material that you need to decrypt the conversation is not permanently stored anywhere. It's generated for a single TLS session and then discarded, ensuring that no one, even the original parties, can retroactively decrypt the conversation.